# Is there a place to look for statistics on most useful packages?

Tags: package

Emacs is a powerful editor (or operating system disguised in a text editor), and some packages are extremely powerful - they improve efficiency diagrammatically.

It might be useful to spend limited time on learning and getting efficient with the most useful packages. Is there a such place to look for statistics or votes on most useful packages?

Comment: The packages build efficient diagrams?:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Useful" is quite subjective, but the popular packages are probably useful to a lot of people.

The most popular elisp projects on github can be found here https://github.com/search?l=emacs-lisp&o=desc&q=stars%3A%3E1&s=stars&type=Repositories. But there are three entries right in the top ten which don't belong there.

And then there is http://www.melpa.org/#/?sort=downloads&asc=false. Here packages that are still under development tend to accumulate more downloads.

Despite these deficits these two resources should give you fairly accurate representation.

Answer (score 7):

I am just using [Paradox](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/paradox) as a replacement for `list-packages`. It displays the number of GitHub stars and has the ability to sort by stars.

[image]

Just try it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to refine a bit the answer by @tarsius, here's a
[query](https://github.com/search?q=language%3A%22Emacs+Lisp%22+stars%3A%3E50+pushed%3A%3E2014-12-20&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories)
for repositories with >50 stars, that were updated after a week ago.
It only gives 58 results. If you want more, you can lower the amount
of stars, or take an earlier date.